# Calculating definite integral of smooth function in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I have the following code which plots the graph of `(1 - x^2)^n` for `n=1,3,5,7`. Is there a way to calculate the integrals from -1 to 1 directly in pgfplots? The goal is to have normalized functions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
  compat/show suggested version=false,
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{kn}{1}{%
  % should be normalized dividing it by its integral from -1 to 1
  \pgfmathparse{(1 - x^2)^#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
      ymin=-0.2, ymax=5,
      xtick={-1,1},
      ytick={1},
      every axis plot/.append style={
        smooth,
        domain=-1:1,
      },
    ]

    \addplot [red] {kn(1)};
    \addplot [blue] {kn(3)};
    \addplot [yellow] {kn(5)};
    \addplot [green] {kn(7)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might try sagetex, which can handle almost any integral known, but is easiest to use on Linux machines, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Accurate solution based on `expl3`

In this solution, each of the needed integrals is precomputed exactly once using the very accurate `l3fp` engine and 40 rectangles for the midpoint rule method (the number of rectangles is just a parameter and can be freely changed).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
  compat/show suggested version=false,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l__noibe_result_fp
\fp_new:N \l__noibe_currentx_fp
\fp_new:N \l__noibe_deltax_fp

% Compute an approximation of the integral of a function over an interval
% using the midpoint rule.
%
% Arguments: macro or tl var for storing the result, unary function, interval
% start, interval end, number of rectangles
\cs_new_protected:Npn \noibe_set_to_midpoint_rule_riemann_sum:NNnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \fp_zero:N \l__noibe_result_fp
    \fp_set:Nn \l__noibe_deltax_fp { (#4 - #3) / (#5) }
    \fp_set:Nn \l__noibe_currentx_fp { #3 + 0.5*\l__noibe_deltax_fp }

    \int_step_inline:nn {#5}
      {
        \fp_add:Nn \l__noibe_result_fp { #2 { \l__noibe_currentx_fp } }
        \fp_add:Nn \l__noibe_currentx_fp { \l__noibe_deltax_fp }
      }

    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { \l__noibe_deltax_fp * \l__noibe_result_fp } }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \noibe_set_to_midpoint_rule_riemann_sum:NNnnn { c }

% Macro name stem for results, parameter, nb rectangles
\cs_new_protected:Npn \noibe_compute_kn_integral:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \noibe__tmp_function:n ##1 { (1 - (##1)^2)^(#2) }
    \noibe_set_to_midpoint_rule_riemann_sum:cNnnn { #1 \int_to_roman:n {#2} }
      \noibe__tmp_function:n { -1 } { 1 } {#3}
  }

% Document-level interface
\NewDocumentCommand \computeKnIntegral { m m m }
  {
    \noibe_compute_kn_integral:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Compute the integrals for parameters 1, 3, 5, 7
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, 3, 5, 7}{%
  \computeKnIntegral{knIntegral}{#1}{40}% 40 is the number of rectangles
}

% Declare a kn function with two arguments: the parameter and the variable ('x')
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{kn}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}%
    \pgfmathfloattoint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \edef\theKnIntegral{%
      \csname knIntegral\romannumeral\pgfmathresult\space\endcsname}%
    \pgfmathparse{ (1 - (#2)^2)^(#1) / \theKnIntegral }%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      enlarge x limits=0.1,
      enlarge y limits=auto,
      every axis plot/.append style={smooth, domain=-1:1},
    ]

    \addplot [red] {kn(1, x)};
    \addplot [blue] {kn(3, x)};
    \addplot [yellow] {kn(5, x)};
    \addplot [green] {kn(7, x)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Solution based on `pgfmath`

The following solution uses `pgfmath` with its `fpu` library to compute the integrals (exactly once each). I use only 20 rectangles here not because of slowness, but because the `fpu` engine of `pgfmath` is not very accurate and I don't want to accumulate too many errors due to a high number of operations (with this engine, the number of significant digits is quite small compared to what `l3fp`—the engine used to compute the integrals in the first solution—offers).

There is a commented-out code path that provides a workaround in case you encounter a `pgfmath` error message mentioning `@@str@@:`. I needed this workaround a couple of days ago, but after todays's upgrade of my TeX Live packages (from Debian unstable), it appears not to be necessary anymore (and even causes an error). So, only enable this workaround if you get the error.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
  compat/show suggested version=false,
}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\makeatletter

% Workaround for a problem I had before the last update of my TeX Live
% packages (Debian unstable). Uncomment the definition if you have an error
% message mentioning '@@str@@:'
% \newcommand*{\my@decode@fpu@string@argument}[2]{%
%   \begingroup
%     \let\pgfmath@basic@stack@push@operand\@firstofone
%     \edef\my@tmp{%
%       \endgroup\def\noexpand#2%
%         {\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
%            \pgfmathfloat@stack@push@operand@single@str #1\relax}}}%
%   \my@tmp
% }

% Compute an approximation of the integral of a function over an interval
% using the midpoint rule.
%
% Arguments: function (prefixed with \pgfmath@fpu@stringmarker), x_min, x_max,
%            number of rectangles.
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{midrule}{4}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfset{fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\my@result}{0}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\my@delta@x}{((#3) - (#2)) / (#4)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\my@x}{(#2) + 0.5*\my@delta@x}%
    % If you have an error message mentioning '@@str@@:', uncomment this line
    % and comment out the following '\def\my@funcname{#1}' line:
    % \expandafter\my@decode@fpu@string@argument\expandafter{#1}{\my@funcname}%
    \def\my@funcname{#1}%
    %
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {1,...,#4}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\my@result}{\my@result + \my@funcname(\my@x)}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\my@x}{\my@x + \my@delta@x}%
    }%
    %
    \pgfmathparse{\my@delta@x * \my@result}%
    \pgfset{fpu=false}%
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\defineknForParam}[2]{%
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{#1#2}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(1 - (##1)^2)^(#2)}%
  }%
}

% Define functions kn1, kn3, kn5 and kn7.
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, 3, 5, 7}{%
  \defineknForParam{knbase}{#1}%
  % Compute and store the integral corresponding to parameter #1. 20 is the
  % number of rectangles used for the midpoint rule.
  \pgfmathmidrule{"knbase#1"}{-1}{1}{20}%
  \csedef{knIntegral\romannumeral #1\space}{\pgfmathresult}%
  %
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{kn#1}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ knbase#1(##1) / \csuse{knIntegral\romannumeral #1\space} }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      enlarge x limits=0.1,
      enlarge y limits=auto,
      every axis plot/.append style={smooth, domain=-1:1},
    ]

    \addplot [red] {kn1(x)};
    \addplot [blue] {kn3(x)};
    \addplot [yellow] {kn5(x)};
    \addplot [green] {kn7(x)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1). Very good programming skill.

Comment: @ferahfeza Thank you; at least someone appreciated my efforts. :-)

Comment: I have updated the solution that computes the integrals with `pgfmath`+ its `fpu` engine so that, as the `l3fp`-based solution, it computes each of the needed integrals only once. Also, the workaround for strange passing of  string arguments to `pgfmath` functions when the `fpu` is enabled is not needed for me anymore after today's upgrade of my TeX Live packages (and it causes an error); therefore, I have commented it out. Only people who get an error message mentioning `@@str@@:` should enable the commented-out code path.

Answer (score 2):

A `sagetex` solution. I've grabbed the code from a previous answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254330/how-to-plot-reciprocal-of-gamma-function-in-latex/254349#254349) and modified it to fit your question. The code could certainly be simplified by removing lines giving you options on what the graph should look like.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
####### SCREEN SETUP #####################
LowerX = -1.0
UpperX = 1.0
LowerY = -0.2
UpperY = 1.8
step = .01
Scale = 1.0
xscale=1.0
yscale=1.0
#####################TIKZ PICTURE SET UP ###########
output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"[line cap=round,line join=round,x=8.75cm,y=8cm]"
output += r"\begin{axis}["
output += r"grid = none,"
#Change "both" to "none" in above line to remove graph paper
output += r"minor tick num=4,"
output += r"every major grid/.style={Red!30, opacity=1.0},"
output += r"every minor grid/.style={ForestGreen!30, opacity=1.0},"
output += r"height= %f\textwidth,"%(yscale)
output += r"width = %f\textwidth,"%(xscale)
output += r"thick,"
output += r"black,"
output += r"axis lines=center,"
#Comment out above line to have graph in a boxed frame (no axes)
output += r"domain=%f:%f,"%(LowerX,UpperX)
output += r"line join=bevel,"
output += r"xmin=%f,xmax=%f,ymin= %f,ymax=%f,"%(LowerX,UpperX,LowerY, UpperY)
#output += r"xticklabels=\empty,"
#output += r"yticklabels=\empty,"
output += r"major tick length=5pt,"
output += r"minor tick length=0pt,"
output += r"major x tick style={black,very thick},"
output += r"major y tick style={black,very thick},"
output += r"minor x tick style={black,thin},"
output += r"minor y tick style={black,thin},"
#output += r"xtick=\empty,"
#output += r"ytick=\empty"
output += r"]"
##############FUNCTIONS#################################
##FUNCTION 1
t1 =  var('t1')
const1 = numerical_integral(1-x^2, -1, 1, max_points=100)
x1_coords = srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)
y1_coords = [((1-t1^2)/const1[0]).n(digits=6) for t1 in x1_coords]
output += r"\addplot[thin, NavyBlue, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x1_coords)):
    if (y1_coords[i])<LowerY or (y1_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f,inf) "%(x1_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f,%f) "%(x1_coords[i],y1_coords[i])
output += r"};"
##FUNCTION 2 #########################################
t2 =  var('t2')
const2 = numerical_integral((1-x^2)^3, -1, 1, max_points=100)
x2_coords = srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)
y2_coords = [((1-t2^2)^3/const2[0]).n(digits=6) for t2 in x2_coords]
output += r"\addplot[thin, Orchid, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x2_coords)):
    if (y2_coords[i])<LowerY or (y2_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f,inf) "%(x2_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f,%f) "%(x2_coords[i],y2_coords[i])
output += r"};"
##FUNCTION 3 ##############################################
t3 =  var('t3')
const3 = numerical_integral((1-x^2)^5, -1, 1, max_points=100)
x3_coords = srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)
y3_coords = [((1-t3^2)^5/const3[0]).n(digits=6) for t3 in x3_coords]
output += r"\addplot[thin, Peach, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x3_coords)):
    if (y3_coords[i])<LowerY or (y3_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f, inf) "%(x3_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f, %f) "%(x3_coords[i],y3_coords[i])
output += r"};"
##FUNCTION 3 ##############################################
t4 =  var('t4')
const4 = numerical_integral((1-x^2)^7, -1, 1, max_points=100)
x4_coords = srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)
y4_coords = [((1-t4^2)^5/const4[0]).n(digits=6) for t4 in x4_coords]
output += r"\addplot[thin, ForestGreen, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x3_coords)):
    if (y4_coords[i])<LowerY or (y4_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f, inf) "%(x4_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f, %f) "%(x4_coords[i],y4_coords[i])
output += r"};"
##### COMMENT OUT A LINE OF SAGESILENT BY STARTING WITH #
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

Running in Cocalc we get:
[image]

The `sagetex` package requires a computer algebra system, SAGE, in order to work. Installing it and getting it to work nicely with LaTeX on Windows computers can be problematic at times, as @Benjamin McKay comments. A free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account avoids these problems as your work is done in the cloud. Cocalc performance has deteriorated a bit over the last few months but should be good enough for light work like this.

NOTE: The output looks different than your picture. I did a sanity check for n=1 getting an integral of 1-x^2 to be 4/3 over -1 to 1. The height of 1-x^2 at 0 is 1 and 1/(4/3) is 3/4.

The CTAN documentation on `sagetex` is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex). The documentation for SAGE is [here](https://www.sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Another, accurate solution using PSTricks. It (ab)uses `\pstODEsolve` (**RKF45**) for computing the definite integrals.
[image]

`latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-plot,pstricks-add}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% I(n)=int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^n dt
% #1: n
% #2: PS variable for result I(n)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\I(#1)#2{%     two output points are enough---v   v---y[0](-1) (initial value)
  \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{#2}{y[0]}{-0.999}{1}{2}{0.0}{(1-t^2)^#1}
  %            integration interval t_a---^    ^---t_b
  %  From ret value `#2', we throw away initial value y(n,-1)
  \pstVerb{/#2 #2 exch pop def}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
% compute and save the definite integrals to int*
\I(1){int1}% n=1
\I(3){int3}% n=3
\I(5){int5}% n=5
\I(7){int7}% n=7
%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.4,-0.7)(0.5,5)
\begin{psgraph}[xAxisLabel={$x$},yAxisLabel={$y$},linewidth=0.5pt,
    Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5, arrows=->](0,0)(-1.2,0)(1.2,1.7){6cm}{!} % x-y-axis with same unit
  \psplot[linecolor=red,plotpoints=100,algebraic]{-1}{1}{ (1-x^2)^1 / int1 }
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,plotpoints=100,algebraic]{-1}{1}{ (1-x^2)^3 / int3 }
  \psplot[linecolor=yellow,plotpoints=100,algebraic]{-1}{1}{ (1-x^2)^5 / int5 }
  \psplot[linecolor=green,plotpoints=100,algebraic]{-1}{1}{ (1-x^2)^7 / int7 }
\end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```